# Simplifying the process of creating a summary table

Tags: r

I am pretty sure I am complicating things. I have a data frame with p variables (here: `v1` to `v3`) and two factor variable (here: `sex` and `unemp`):

```
> head(df)
  sex unemp v1 v2 v3
1   0     0  2  4  4
2   0     0  2  1  1
3   1     0  3  3  5
4   1     1  2  3  5
5   0     0  1  2  5
6   1     0  3  5  4
```

I now would like to modify (i.e. compute median and mean and then rearrange the summary table) my data in such way that the resulting data frame looks like this (for men or women):

```
> df.res.men
   median.unemp.1 median.unemp.0 mean.unemp.1 mean.unemp.0
v1            2.0            2.0     2.666667     2.391304
v2            2.0            3.5     2.500000     3.369565
v3            4.5            3.0     4.166667     2.956522
```

Here is the full code:

```
library(plyr)
## generate data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(sex=rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
                 unemp=rbinom(100, 1, 0.2),
                 v1=sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 v2=sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 v3=sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
                 )
head(df)

## compute mean and median for all variables by sex and unemp
df.mean <- ddply(df, .(unemp, sex), .fun=colMeans, na.rm=TRUE)
df.mean
df.median <- ddply(df, .(unemp, sex), .fun=function(x)apply(x,2,median, na.rm=TRUE))
df.median

## rearrange summary table
df.res.men <- cbind(t(subset(df.median, sex==0 & unemp==1)),
                 t(subset(df.median, sex==0 & unemp==0)),
                 t(subset(df.mean, sex==0 & unemp==1)),
                 t(subset(df.mean, sex==0 & unemp==0)))
df.res.men <- df.res.men[-c(1:2),]
colnames(df.res.men) <- c("median.unemp.1", "median.unemp.0", 
                          "mean.unemp.1", "mean.unemp.0")
df.res.men
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
library(plyr); library(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df, id = c('sex', 'unemp'))
df2 <- ddply(dfm, .(variable, unemp, sex), summarize, 
  avg = mean(value), med = median(value))

df2m <- melt(df2, id = 1:3, variable.name = 'sum_fun')
df_0 <- dcast(df2m, sex + variable ~ sum_fun + unemp, subset = .(sex == 0))

   sex variable    avg_0  avg_1 med_0 med_1
1   0       v1 2.794872 3.0000     3   3.5
2   0       v2 3.102564 2.8750     3   3.0
3   0       v3 3.205128 3.1875     3   4.0
```

Comment: @Ramnath -- Thanks for catching that change in functionality between `reshape` and `reshape2`. Rather than confuse anybody, I've deleted my answer. Also, +1 to yours.

Comment: @Josh. I think you should keep your answer. It is very elegant. You could add a note making it clear that the functionality is from `reshape` and was dropped from `reshape2`.

Comment: @Ramnath -- You're right. It's good to leave the answer there, so I've now 'de-cloaked' it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two-line solution using `reshape` alone. The default column names need a bit of work, but the syntax of the `melt()` and `cast()` statements is nicely expressive.

(**One important note** -- unlike `reshape`, `reshape2` can not take a vector of summary function names as its `fun.aggregate` argument, as I've done below with `c(mean, median)`. Thanks to Ramnath for pointing that out.)

```
library(reshape)
dmelt <- melt(df, id=c('sex', 'unemp'))

# Results for sex 0
cast(dmelt, variable ~ unemp, c(mean, median), subset = sex==0)
#   variable   0_mean 0_median   1_mean 1_median
# 1       v1 2.391304      2.0 2.666667      2.0
# 2       v2 3.369565      3.5 2.500000      2.0
# 3       v3 2.956522      3.0 4.166667      4.5

# Results for sex 1
cast(dmelt, variable ~ unemp, c(mean, median), subset = sex==1)
#   variable   0_mean 0_median   1_mean 1_median
# 1       v1 3.027778        3 2.416667      2.0
# 2       v2 2.638889        2 2.750000      3.0
# 3       v3 3.027778        3 2.583333      2.5
```

Comment: nice one. note that hadley removed this feature of applying multiple aggregate functions in `reshape2`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without reshaping data.

```
f <- function(x) rbind(each(mean,median)(na.omit(x)))
#
# This should work but it doesn't.
# It almost work except labelling output with function names
#
df.res <- ddply(df,.(unemp, sex),.fun=numcolwise(f))
#
# Some workaround
#
df.res <- dlply(df,.(unemp, sex),.fun=numcolwise(f))
df.res <- cbind(attr(df.res,"split_labels"),do.call(rbind,df.res))
```